# reset the color of a previously pressed button after another button is pressed c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm using C# windows form application, and i'm facing a problem resetting a button's back Color.

By clicking a button I need it to change its back color and reset the  back color of previously pressed button.

Please note that i have lots of buttons in the form and i'm using "sender" to apply same clicking event to all buttons.

Comment: And where is the problem? What you have tried?

Comment: show some code that you have written

Comment: Share you code as well. I think you might need to keep track which button was clicked.

Comment: private void Common_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
           {
       
                   Button btn = sender as Button;
                   if (btn != null)
                   btn.BackColor = Color.Blue;
      
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to keep track of the last button that was clicked.  Add a private field and then manipulate it in the on click event handler:

```
class Form1 : Form
{
    private Button _lastButtonClicked;

    protected void ClickHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_lastButtonClicked != null)
           _lastButtonClicked.BackColor = Color.whatever;

        _lastButtonClicked = sender as Button;
        _lastButtonClicked = Color.newcolor;
    }
}
```